# how to make my code to keep asking to input names from the array until stop is inputed

Tags: java, arrays, parallel-processing

I need to make my code to keep asking to input flower names(from the options in my array) until "stop" is inputted, keep in mind i am working with a parallel array that also gives me the prices of the flowers. at the end i need a total of all the flowers inputted. thanks for you help.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] flowers = {"petunia", "parse", "rose", "violet", "daisy"};
        double[] cost = {.50, .75, 1.50, 1.00, .80};
        System.out.println("Please enter a name of one flower ex.");

        for (String f : flowers) {
            System.out.print(f + ",");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("please enter your flower :  ");
        String flow;
         String stop = "stop";
        flow = s1.nextLine();
        System.out.println("the flower you chousse si " + flow);

        for (int i = 0; i < flowers.length; i++) {
            double d = cost[i];
            {
                if (flow.equalsIgnoreCase(flowers[i])) {
                    System.out.println("the flowers price " + cost[i]);
                }
              //  else (flow.equalsIgnoreCase(stop)){
                    System.out.println("your total is ");
                }

            }

        }

        // TODO code application logic here
    }

}
```

Comment: Use break when it equals "stop"

Comment: You need to put your request for input, and then scan of user input into a loop that exits when their input equals "stop".

Answer (score 0):

I think you are expecting something like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] flowers = { "petunia", "parse", "rose", "violet", "daisy" };
    double[] cost = { .50, .75, 1.50, 1.00, .80 };
    System.out.println("Please enter a name of one flower ex.");

    for (String f : flowers) {
        System.out.print(f + ",");
    }
    System.out.println("\n");

    Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("please enter your flower :  ");
    String flow = s1.nextLine();
    double total = 0.0;

    while (!flow.equals("stop")) {
        System.out.println("the flower you chousse si " + flow);
        for (int i = 0; i < flowers.length; i++) {
            {
                if (flow.equalsIgnoreCase(flowers[i])) {
                    System.out.println("the flowers price " + cost[i]);
                    total += cost[i];
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.print("\nplease enter your flower :  ");
        flow = s1.nextLine();
    }

    System.out.println("\nyour total is " + total);
}
```

You can use HashMap key, value pairs, rather than using arrays for these type of scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Map.of, String.join, Map.containsKey and Map.get you get more concise Java code. Please see below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    var flowers = Map.of("petunia", .50, "parse", .75, "rose", 1.50, "violet", 1.00, "daisy", .80);
    System.out.println("Please enter a name of one flower ex.");
    System.out.print(String.join(", ", flowers.keySet()));

    Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    double total = 0.0;

    String flow;
    do {
        System.out.print("\nplease enter your flower :  ");
        flow = s1.nextLine();
        var f = flow.toLowerCase();
        if (flowers.containsKey(f)) {
            var cost = flowers.get(f);
            System.out.println("the flowers price " + cost);
            total += cost;
        }
    } while (!flow.equals("stop"));

    System.out.println("\nyour total is " + total);
}
```

Comment: @carlos flores Does my answer help you?

Comment: dude, that works beautifully. i was missing completely setting the total value to 0.0 to started the operation. now i'm working on trying to sort the two parallel array and keep them parallel after the sorting.